# Are these functions equal to each other?

Tags: functions

$$f^8(x)=(f^2)^4(x)$$
$$f^8(x)=[f^2(x)]^4$$
Are they equal? I'm confused about these. Please help me clarify this and explain to me why it is so.

Comment: what is your definition of $f^{n}(x)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f^8(x)$ means the application of the function $f$ to $x$ 8 times, i.e. $f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(x))))))))$, then the first is not the same as the second. If however $f^8(x)$ means the $f(x)$ multiplied by itself 8 times, i.e. $f(x)\times f(x)\times ... \times f(x)$ (eight times), then yes they are equal.

Comment: Do u mean that there are 2 different situations?

Comment: sure, it depends on how you define $f^n(x)$...

Comment: e.g. by convention $\sin^n x = (\sin x)^n$ but e.g. $f(x)=x+4$ you would normally have $f^n(x)$ as $n$ applications of the function, in this case adding 4 $n$ times